# forget a modified/un-merged file from git status once added to .gitignore

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've few modified files on server. I've added them to .gitignore file. Now when doing `git pull origin master` still those files were present there. So I used following command to remove them from git status

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
```

Now when I'm doing `git status` it shows many files are deleted.

Ex. `deleted: skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/minicart.js`

Thought still these files are present on server(I want them to be present too)

As my next step should I do `git commit -am "Remove ignored files"` ? 
I don't want these files to be removed from server, I want to remove them from `git status` only and further I should be able to do `git pull origin development` without any conflict.

Comment: Does git think you're in the middle of a merge still?

Comment: @JohnDrouhard: Sorry, I'm not sure about that. How I can identify?